# Looking for a job in Data Science. Should my poker career be included?

Tags: resume

I am a recently graduated Mathematician in Western Europe and looking for my first job. My interest would going towards the data-related world (Data Analysis, Data Science, Statistics...) in a business environment.

I have a three-year "gap" on my history, though, as I lived as a professional online poker player during those years before resuming my education. I am afraid that many companies will not like that on my CV. Are my fears justified?

Even if many companies will refuse hiring me for my previous job, is there anything I can really do? They will ask for that gap anyway and then I will either have to adress the topic or lie, which I don't really think is a way forward.

It may also be the case that some recruiters (Western Europe) find the "poker thing" as something that makes a difference between myself and the rest of the candidates. I am not sure about that. What are your thoughts?

**EDIT**: I've already read [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10529/should-i-include-poker-on-my-resume?noredirect=1&lq=1), but the advice there is a bit outdated as both the job marketplace and the poker world have changed a lot since 2013. Playing online poker for a living was quite common in 2013, now only a handful of people do. Also, the recruiting processes of many companies have been updated and the skills needed quite different (almost nobody knew what Machine Learning or Big Data were five years ago, for instance)

It's not region-specific, I haven't made any coaching/material (which is the focus of many answers) and, finally, I am not a software developer (so "make a poker-based code thing" does not apply)

Comment: @gnat I've already read that question, but the advice there is a bit outdated (both the job marketplace and the poker world have changed a lot since 2013). It's not region-specific, I haven't made any coaching/material (which is the focus of many answers) and, finally, I am not a software development (so the "make a poker-based code thing" does not apply)

Comment: @David The answer still applies.

Comment: Thank you for not only not giving an answer, but also preventing others from providing one

Comment: the rules apply to everyone. "both the job marketplace and the poker world have changed a lot since 2013" is not a reasonable argument since it does not change the answer. Even if these arguments were true it wouldn't change the accepted answer in the duplicate. Showcase how your experience makes you a better employee than someone with a gap. Its up to you to figure out how the skills are transferable to the field you're seeking a job in. Imagine if we'd get a unique question from poker players making a transition into all the various industries. It would result in a lot of spam.

Comment: @David - if you can explain *how* you think things have changed since that other question, in a way that shows your question could get different answers, that may help your case for reopening this question. I'm willing to guess that many people here are not familiar enough with professional poker to know the significance of any changes, so it's hard to know if your question is eligible for reopening or not.

Comment: @dwizum I understand that not everyone knows how every sector works. That's why I don't like people who don't understand my situation closing my question. When I don't understand someone's situation, I move on. I don't feel the need for closing the question. Otherwise we should reopen the site as "Software Development Workplace Stack Exchange" (which would represent the reality of the site much more closely)

Comment: @Jonast92 Since you are closing the different ones, a unique (rather than many) question is exactly what you are aiming for! Playing online poker for a living was quite common in 2013, now only a handful of people do. Also, the recruiting processes of many companies have been updated and the skills needed quite different (almost nobody knew what Machine Learning or Big Data were five years ago, for instance). If you read the answers to those questions, most of those don't apply here for the reasons I already stated

Comment: I feel your pain, and I would like to see the question opened (I've already voted to reopen because of my interest in the data science aspect.) But I also understand the other side of the equation: just saying "my situation is different" doesn't really motivate people to believe you, without at least some kind of explanation. Otherwise we would just be taking everyone's word at face value and reopening every single question. There needs to be at least some degree of justification besides just "you should believe me."

Comment: I make generous side income playing poker myself. I am very familiar with the industry. I disagree that the changes of the industries have any effect on the answers that can be provided. I agree, however, that additional and more general helpful answers can be provided to the question but right now its not addressing anything more than the other question already has. That's the problem. Rather than stating that the duplicate is not a duplicate it would be better to address how the current answers are not applicable. The reason that you're not a programmer is not a valid reason.

Comment: @Jonast92 Let's see. The original question goes like: "Should a programmer include poker on his resume". A bunch of correct programming-focused answers pop-up. Now I want to ask a similar question applied to a different situation but for some reason I am directed to those programming-specific answers

Comment: @David The advice is the same. If you can apply the knowledge to the field you want to get into then by all means do it, while realizing that it's a risk. If you're convincing that the skills are usable and transferable (i.e. self employed, problem solving, hard working etc etc) then you may be able to portrait traits that a potential employer might desire over a gap. If this is not enough for you then you need to address better how this advice is not enough. What more are you looking for?

Comment: @David, in the universe of jobs, Data Analysis, Data Science, Statistics...Machine Learning, Big Data are all at least partially technical jobs and not far from software development.  "I've been playing poker professionally for n years and I want to become a baker (or a car salesman or a bus driver,...)" would have a better argument for not being a duplicate.

Comment: @cdkMoose I will publish that question only to see how someone marks it as a duplicate of a random baking question :)

Comment: @David and others IMO a compelling argument for this not being a duplicate is that the other question is about someone with previous work experience, while this question is about someone looking for their first job (of a different type).

Comment: @JimG. This question has already been closed and reopened for that reason. I've already explained the reasons why this question is different

Answer (score 3):

You should **include in your resume those experiences that you feel best demonstrate your capabilities.** I would find a poker career interesting for a number of potential reasons:

1. **You’ve successfully navigated being self-employed.** Self-employment, regardless of your source of revenue, is a challenging responsibility and very transferable experience to managing a budget or P&L for a team/department.
2. **You’ve demonstrated a true knack for quantitative reasoning.** Without the benefit of being able to see your fellow players, you had to depend on an understanding of the mechanics and statistics of poker to be successful. You not only knew the odds, you knew how to act on them.
3. **You’ve demonstrated an understanding of human reasoning.** You’ve gained an insight into the way people take risks and respond to rewards in your experience with poker. This is universally relevant to business.
4. **It’s interesting and unique.** The experience definitely would stand out against a stack of average resumes.
5. **It helps me understand *you***. You chose to devote a substantial chunk of your life to poker. The experience is and the decision to pursue poker are both a part of who you are.

Best of luck in your job search!

Answer (score 1):

Your CV should include the **most relevant** experience you have which makes you suitable for the job you're applying for.

Did you use your knowledge and skills in statistics and data science during your poker career? If yes then they could be worth including, as long as you're able to highlight them as the key skills you used to be successful.

If not then don't worry - since you're at the start of your data science career, it doesn't matter very much what you did before you graduated. **You don't actually have a gap on your CV at all!**

You could have been working full-time in fast food for those three years, or as a lawyer, or studying part time, and it would be just as irrelevant as playing full-time poker. Your data science CV starts from the point you *graduated* with your degree, unless you choose to make it start earlier.

Personally on my CV I have a degree that took three years longer than expected due to circumstances in my personal life. I list my graduation date only (i.e. not the date I entered the program), because that's all that's relevant. No one has ever asked me for further details.